# Enforce type in structured object

Tags: typescript, types, casting, declaration

How can we enforce the type of properties inside a structured object?
In the code below, I'd like to avoid defining all my array elements (second example) before creating the array.

```
type EcommerceFlow =  ("REVENUE" | "ATC" | "ADD_INSURANCE" );
interface UniversalConf {
  trackingId: string;
  eCommerceFlows: Array<EcommerceFlow>;
}

// how to keep this syntax (single object declaration) with compiler checks?
const providers = [
  <UniversalConf> {
    "providerCode": "UA", // Compiler does not complain about non-defined property
    "trackingId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eCommerceFlows": ["REVENUE", "BAD_FLOW"] // Compiler does not complain about BAD_FLOW
  }
]

const uaConf:UniversalConf = {
  "providerCode": "UA", // Compiler complains about non-defined property
  "trackingId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
  "eCommerceFlows": ["REVENUE", "BAD_FLOW"] // Compiler complains about BAD_FLOW (and this is fine)
};
const providers2 = [ uaConf ];
```

Comment: `const providers: UniversalConf[] = [...]`? `<UniversalConf>[...]` is an [*assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions), it's telling the compiler that *is* a `UniversalConf` (even if it thinks otherwise). But note that having an extra prop isn't a problem, as anything consuming `UniversalConf` won't be able to access it anyway.

Comment: I understand the assertion part, but I'd like a way to have a real type checking (declaration like), while keeping the single object structure.
Also, to me the extra-prop is a problem, as I want to ensure no typos at compilation time from other developers (in reality my type is more complex, with optional properties. Optional properties could be miss-written with no error then).

Comment: `const providers: UniversalConf[] = []` gives you type checking. But extra props are only checked on assignment of a single object literal as far as I'm aware. At a certain point you have to rely on basic competence - the "expected" optional names will likely be suggested/autocompleted by IDEs/editors anyway, and if they're optional then missing them shouldn't break anything compile wise (tests will still fail on the functionality being wrong though).

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, this array can contain other types (for which the same issue stands)
Indeed it will compile but it will not behave as expected by the developer (debugging, lost time, ... ;))

Comment: That wasn't in the question, but `const providers: (UniversalConf | ...)[]`? You'll get errors if the values don't match *any* of the allowed contents. Or `const providers: [UniversalConf, ...]` if they're known positionally: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple.

Comment: Actually I'm seeing excess prop checks within the array literal, too: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAogxgewLZIgJzhAYgGwQdygF4ooAKAIgCUYA1GAOQFUYKoAfKCgQQBUBhNpx4AREQH0AkgwDKTKtwb9WUAJQBuAFABLAHbB0AMwCGmKE13aAbugDOxnPwS7DUAN6bSwNKYDWegHNJABMALihbb0CtUggnFHRMXAJbcO40HxAAHnhkVAxsPHwAPi0AX01NRF1IqDA0BCttYLtwi2s7BycXAG0AXWIoHs93EdIKesbm9CcWinCKJm4KABooAHp1qHiwbRx0KGCECFsoXQRgKEQkMBxjPShjACMEAFdL890AWhbDPQhgnUGpA0KAxlxvH5AiF5lwABoIxFI1bgihxPKJQopWE9ah0RgsCgDTbbZC7fZoQ7HU7nS7XW73XSPF7vKAAIW4EiwABkAPIAdRGFT6miAA)

Comment: Yep !!! Thks.
If you write an answer with the "const providers: (UniversalConf | ...)[]" comment I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type `<UniversalConf>` in

```
const providers = [
  <UniversalConf> {
    "providerCode": "UA", // Compiler does not complain about non-defined property
    "trackingId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eCommerceFlows": ["REVENUE", "BAD_FLOW"] // Compiler does not complain about BAD_FLOW
  }
]
```

is an [*assertion*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions); it *suppresses* type checking, telling the compiler "I know what this is". Instead, you want to tell the compiler what you expect the identifier's type to be, and let it check the value:

```
const providers: UniversalConf[] = [
  {
    "providerCode": "UA",
    "trackingId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eCommerceFlows": ["REVENUE", "BAD_FLOW"]
  }
]
```

If you have an array that could contain multiple possible types, you can use a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) to represent it:

```
const providers: (UniversalConf | ...)[] = [
  {
    "providerCode": "UA",
    "trackingId": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "eCommerceFlows": ["REVENUE", "BAD_FLOW"]
  }
]
```